# How to choose asymmetric biplots in correspondence analysis

Tags: correspondence-analysis

I have categorical data on Police Stations against Crime categories on a 2-way contingency table. I have an asymmetric row map and column map from correspondence analysis using XLSTAT. Which one of the two maps should be used to interpret the results?

Comment: the asymmetric plot has the advantage of comparing rows with columns and the coordinates of it needed .. as an excel sheet for coordinates for each

Answer (score 1):

Let me simply cite Help from SPSS Correspondence analysis

> Normalization Method. Choose one of the following alternatives:
>
> • Symmetrical. For each dimension, the row scores are the weighted
>   average of the column scores divided by the matching singular value,
>   and the column scores are the weighted average of row scores divided
>   by the matching singular value. Use this method if you want to examine
>   the differences or similarities between the categories of the two
>   variables.
>
> • Principal. The distances between row points and column points are
>   approximations of the distances in the correspondence table according
>   to the selected distance measure. Use this method if you want to
>   examine differences between categories of either or both variables
>   instead of differences between the two variables.
>
> • Row principal. The distances between row points are approximations
>   of the distances in the correspondence table according to the selected
>   distance measure. The row scores are the weighted average of the
>   column scores. Use this method if you want to examine differences or
>   similarities between categories of the row variable.
>
> • Column principal. The distances between column points are
>   approximations of the distances in the correspondence table according
>   to the selected distance measure. The column scores are the weighted
>   average of the row scores. Use this method if you want to examine
>   differences or similarities between categories of the column variable.
>
> • Custom. You must specify a value between –1 and 1. A value of –1
>   corresponds to column principal. A value of 1 corresponds to row
>   principal. A value of 0 corresponds to symmetrical. All other values
>   spread the inertia over both the row and column scores to varying
>   degrees. This method is useful for making tailor-made biplots.

With Principal method, you can obtain a plot only with row variable categories or only with column variable categories. With the other methods, you get biplot - both variables' categories are shown on the same plot. Symmetrical method is most often used.

I suppose that by `asymmetric row map and column map` you mean row and column principal biplots. There must be a way to request symmetric biplot.